# Error when trying to use WinToUSB to install Windows 7 Ultimate onto a pendrive

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, usb-flash-drive

I wanted to install Windows on an USB drive so that I can use it on different computers. I heard about WinToUSB and gave it a try. At about seventy percent (with three retries) I get an error "Copy file failed.(0x0000008000B40000)". I am using Windows 7 Home Premium, trying to install Windows 7 Ultimate onto a Kingston DataTraveller 3.0 (USB 3.0).

What can I do? I tried three times.

I appreciate any help.

I am NOT talking about installing Windows FROM a pendrive but TO a pendrive.

Update:

I contacted WinToUSB support and after looking at the log file they told me that the iso file I was trying is corrupted. I am going to download the ISO from DigitalRiver and try to see whether it works. Link to forum: http://www.easyuefi.com/forums/showthread.php?tid=41

Comment: So did what you described in the update work?  If so, can you post an answer describing the solution?  That will help others with the same problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the file again and it worked. I think the best solution to prevent this would be to check the Hash of the downloaded file before using it.

Thanks for all the help provided.

Answer (score 1):

From WintoUSB installation notes:

"Windows 7/2008 R2 does not have built-in USB 3.0 support, so Windows 7/2008 R2 will have to be booted from a USB 2.0 port."

Comment: Even though I have a USB 3.0 pendrive, I plug it into a USB 2.0 drive. I have already read through the install notes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "WinUSB Maker". I have several successful Windows 7 installation done using this software with no issues. It has the ability to create a bootable USB pen drive if you have Windows 7 Setup Folders or Setup ISO Image.

Hope this helps!

Comment: According to many articles, WinUSB maker only allows you install os from lettuce. WinToUSB is like Windows To Go. You can use the OS straight from the pendrive, after installing it on the pendrive. However, thank you for your answer.